# Adding outlets and actions in XCode 4 for a Monobjc Application

Tags: macos, xcode4, mono, monobjc

I've been following the tutorials in http://www.monobjc.net/ in order to do a small Mac app using monobjc for the GUI. However they are using Interface Builder 3 in order to create the actions and outlets that are needed and I can't find a way to add these into the app delegate when I edit the xib file in XCode 4. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Are you using MonoDevelop to develop the application ?

Comment: Yes, I am using MonoDevelop 2.8.6.5 on Lion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have updated [the documentation](http://www.monobjc.net/index.php?page=monodevelop-addins-xcode) to include a [step-by-step guide](http://www.monobjc.net/index.php?page=monodevelop-addins-xcode) on how to create action/outlet.

I hope it is clear enough for you to go with Monobjc/MonoDevelop/Xcode.